# Cant copy / paste large text over SSH

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, clipboard

Running ssh from Windows -> linux and I cant paste text larger than ~20 chars. If I do it hangs the session.

This is happening to others in the office using various methods to ssh. cygwin, mobaxterm etc.

It also does not happen with all servers, but the ones it does happen too, always hang.

Any ideas? Bit tricky searching for this issue on google.

Update (on the linux box):

```
ping -M do -s 1472 google.com # ok
ping -M do -s 1473 google.com # icmp_seq=1 Frag needed and DF set (mtu = 1500)
```

Windows:

```
same as linux
```

#### Update

this is not just copy / paste, it seems to have gotten worse and now most things crash the session. `nano some_file.ext` and it will sometimes hang, or `cat some_file.ext` will also hang the session.

Comment: Are you connecting to a local server or remote server? If remote, what is the nature of your router and internet connection?

Comment: Seems to be a MTU trouble. Check the mtu of the server, router and workstation.

Comment: @EEAA It is remote (although some other remote servers work fine), what exactly do you mean with the nature of them?

Comment: @kranteg see update on MTU, dont seem to be the issue

Comment: On your workstation, you can try to put a mtu to 1400 temporarily to be sure.

Comment: @kranteg set to 1400 and made no difference, still cant paste longer than 20

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the switch, router or firewall?

Comment: What are the differences between working servers and failing servers in network configuration (mtu, gateway, provider) ?

Comment: Nothing that I know of, one thing that does work is putty. Can paste long text with putty on these 'broken' servers...

Comment: I propose you wireshark your SSL sessions and look for irregularities immediately before and during the hang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem seems to have come from an automatic update in untangle. No clue what, but after bypassing ssl on untangle it works again.